# CoreCLR/ServiceStack connection pooling

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack with coreclr, hosting on the official MS base coreclr image.

My connection pool settings don't seem to be being respected.

```
  var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
  builder.MaxPoolSize = 20;
  builder.MinPoolSize = 5;
  builder.Pooling = true;
  builder.ApplicationName = "Core-CLR-API";
  builder.WorkstationID = Environment.MachineName;
  var factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(builder.ToString(), SqlServerDialect.Provider);
```

As you can see from my `sp_who2` output, I've more than 20 connections.

Is there some other setting required to make the pool be respected?

[image: sp_who]/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a CoreCLR bug. Fixed in System.Data.SqlClient@4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any public API which gives you further control over this except to make sure each `IDbConnection` opened is disposed of after use as once you dispose of the `IDbConnection` the instance is returned back into the SQL Server connection pool who manages the open DB connections.